# Personal health records software

Tags: software-rec, application, data

Does anybody know personal health records software for Linux?

I want to record blood pressure, pulse, temperature, feel to analyze later. I will write information manually, as my measuring instruments doesn't have connection to PC.

Of course I can just write data to simple plain text file and then plot them with `gnuplot` or `matplotlib` as a true *nix user. But I think that this problem was solved and someone created more comprehensive tool, which for example can store blood analysis results, electrocardiograms, ..., can remind to measure blood pressure and pulse and so on.

I've tried to google it, I've looked on [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_open-source_healthcare_software) but found only huge web-based systems for hospitals (like GNU Health, GNUmed, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

I think you could use *Gnu Health* for this (and if you got plans to start your own hospital or add your family, there´s no problem)

> GNU Health is an official GNU Package, and the Hospital Information
>   System adopted by the United Nations University, International
>   Institute for Global Health, for the implementations and trainings.

http://health.gnu.org/

Comment: >> I've tried to google it, I've looked on this list but found only huge web-based systems for hospitals (like GNU Health, GNUmed, etc.).
I want to use this software for myself only. GNU Health is to big and complicated for this.

Comment: Well, this wasen´t easy... I´ve harvest all kinds of software archive and there seems to be two kinds of software: Big enterprise hospital software (like GNU Health) or very simple software. I´ve found: GaiaEHR (but it´s prob. to big for your need) https://sourceforge.net/projects/gaiaehr/?source=directory Maybe a plain Google Docs or a Google form would be the best option for you. So, all OpenSource guy´s out there - here is a need/call for new software. Good luck !

Comment: Thank you for your search. I think I'll stick to LibreOffice Calc.

Answer (score 1):

Some months back, I searched fruitlessly, for the exact same kind of software. Indeed there are several EMR / PHR systems whose intended usage is by multi-discipline large hostpitals to small public-health clinics. Also, most of them come with features that are unlikely to be useful for personal health record maintenance, needing elaborate configuration, data-base setup etc.

Finally I settled for a google-drive survey form. The downside is that it needs internet connectivity to use, but the upside are several. It's extremely simple to setup and use. Information is already in spreadsheet, so you can do fancy graphs, including pivot tables, correlations etc., and hosting/back-ups for reliability etc. are taken care of for you. Most of all, this system is accessible from my home PCs (running Linux), my Android tablet, my phone, my office laptop etc. Browser-based, cloud-hosted software at it's best.

This answer is perhaps not exactly the answer that you were looking for, and this isn't very Linux'y -- but it works.

Comment: **Backups are most likely *not* taken care of for you.** Case in point: if you accidentally delete the spreadsheet, where do you turn to in order to restore a backup? If you manage to overwrite all the numbers with garbage (or delete them) and save, how do you restore a backup? Etc. *Cloud/online storage has its uses, but any one single copy of anything can never be a backup.* I elaborate on this in the accepted answer to the SuperUser question [How to store and preserve lots of data?](http://superuser.com/a/374561/53590).

Comment: Okay, good point @MichaelKjörling. By backups being taken care of, I was only referring to disc-crash/corruption. Not ones caused by human error on the data itself. However, I believe there are ways and means to even do periodic backups on external (3rd party) services.

Comment: The vast majority of the times when I've needed to restore something from backup, it hasn't been because of all-out storage failure. There's a reason why people always chant *RAID is not backup!*, and it applies pretty well to cloud storage as well. And I reiterate that a single copy can never be a backup; a backup, by definition, is a second, independent copy which is accessible on demand (though not necessarily *immediately* accessible).

Answer (score 1):

Omron Blood Pressure Monitor software

https://github.com/LazyT/obpm

Allows manual entries (which is what you were wanting right?)

Runs on Linux.

Has Analysis option as well.

I use a manual Sphygmomanometer with a stethoscope to obtain Systolic, Diastolic and Pulse Rate readings and then record them using the software above!

Answer (score 0):

OP, can you use Excel or Libre Office or another spreadsheet program? It does graphs for you also. Each tab can be a person, each column can be a measurement: one for date of measurement, one for blood pressure, body weight, blood lab result, etc. That's about as simple as it gets.